# How do I count the number of words with the same length in a array of strings C

Tags: c, arrayofstring

I'm opening and reading a dictionary file and counting how many words are in the file. Then I'm storing each word individually in an array of strings. After that, I sorted the words by length and in alphabetical order, using the funtion `qsort()`. Right now, I'm trying to access the table and count how many words have the same length, but I'm have some difficulties to decide on how I should proceed next. The code I have written so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STR 100

/* Sorting the words by length and alphabtichal order,
being legnth priority number one */

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){

    const char **str_a = (const char **)a;
    const char **str_b = (const char **)b;

    int len1 = strlen(*str_a);
    int len2 = strlen(*str_b);
    if (len1 < len2) return -1;
    if (len1 > len2) return  1;

    return strcmp(*str_a, *str_b);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int i = 0, n_total_palavras = 0;
    char str[MAX_STR];
    int  count = 0;
    char **Words;

    fp = fopen("words.dict", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        exit (0);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp,"%s",str) == 1){
        n_total_palavras++;
    }

    Words = (char **)malloc(n_total_palavras * sizeof (char *));
    if (Words == NULL){
        exit(0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_total_palavras; i++){
        Words[i] = NULL;
         
    }

    rewind (fp);
    while (fscanf(fp,"%s",str) == 1){
       Words[count] = (char*)malloc((strlen(str)+1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(Words[count], str);
        count++;
    }

    qsort(Words, n_total_palavras, sizeof(Words[0]), compare);

    /* for(i = 0; i < n_total_palavras; i++){
        printf("%s\n", Words[i]);
    }
    */



    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to obtain something like:

```
4 letters words: 2018
5 letters words: 170
6 letters words: 10
(...)
```

Any idea on how I should look at this ?

Comment: You should only need to read the file once.  Since the table is sorted by length, all you need do is step through each entry, checking whether the length is the same as for the previous entry, and printing the count when the length changes.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it. Thank you for your answer! @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code implementing what I suggested.  It reads the file once, growing the word list as needed.  It allocates about twice as much space as before each time more space is needed.

I've simplified the comparison function marginally — but the optimizer probably gets close to what I've written anyway.

The code is currently configured not to print the sorted word list.

```
/* SO 7400-7509 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR 100

/*
 * Sorting the words first by length and then in alphabetical order
*/

static int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *str_a = *(const char **)a;
    const char *str_b = *(const char **)b;

    int len1 = strlen(str_a);
    int len2 = strlen(str_b);
    if (len1 < len2)
        return -1;
    if (len1 > len2)
        return 1;

    return strcmp(str_a, str_b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[MAX_STR];
    char **words = 0;
    size_t max_words = 0;
    size_t num_words = 0;
    const char *filename = "words.dict";

    if (argc == 2)
        filename = argv[1];
    else if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [filename]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file '%s' for reading\n",
                argv[0], filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%99s", str) == 1)
    {
        if (num_words >= max_words)
        {
            size_t new_size = (max_words + 2) * 2;
            void *new_space = realloc(words, sizeof(words[0]) * new_size);
            if (new_space == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to allocate %zu pointers\n",
                        argv[0], new_size);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            words = new_space;
            max_words = new_size;
        }
        words[num_words++] = strdup(str);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    qsort(words, num_words, sizeof(words[0]), compare);

    /*
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i+1, words[i]);
    }
    */

     size_t count = 0;
     size_t currlen = strlen(words[0]);
     for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
     {
        size_t length = strlen(words[i]);
        if (length == currlen)
            count++;
        else
        {
            printf("%zu-letter words: %zu\n", currlen, count);
            currlen = length;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%zu-letter words: %zu\n", currlen, count);

    return 0;
}
```

Consider the data file `words.dict`:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
Hawaii
California
Colorado
Alaska
Alabama
Arizona
```

It produces the output:

```
4-letter words: 1
5-letter words: 3
6-letter words: 2
7-letter words: 3
8-letter words: 1
10-letter words: 1
```

Given a variation on the Linux dictionary (it's been mangled so the words are all mono-case, and all punctuation is removed, and duplicates have been removed, the output was:

```
$ timecmd -m -- cw31 ~/src/spelling-bee/sb-wordlist
2022-10-09 13:56:34.935 [PID 94595] cw31 /Users/jonathanleffler/src/spelling-bee/sb-wordlist
1-letter words: 26
2-letter words: 566
3-letter words: 4343
4-letter words: 10359
5-letter words: 21884
6-letter words: 38179
7-letter words: 50447
8-letter words: 58182
9-letter words: 57289
10-letter words: 48591
11-letter words: 39357
12-letter words: 30260
13-letter words: 21642
14-letter words: 14585
15-letter words: 9078
16-letter words: 5325
17-letter words: 3046
18-letter words: 1505
19-letter words: 774
20-letter words: 363
21-letter words: 170
22-letter words: 74
23-letter words: 31
24-letter words: 12
25-letter words: 8
27-letter words: 3
28-letter words: 2
29-letter words: 2
31-letter words: 1
45-letter words: 1
2022-10-09 13:56:35.130 [PID 94595; status 0x0000]  -  0.195s
$ wc -l ~/src/spelling-bee/sb-wordlist
  416105 /Users/jonathanleffler/src/spelling-bee/sb-wordlist
$
```

The 45-letter word for the curious is "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis".

Comment: Your answer was very  helpful and educational. Thank you once again. G bless!

Comment: Meh .. medical dictionary stuff. Normal unabridged is the way to go for purists`:)`

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to me to sort the list of words primarily by length, subsorting by alphabetic sequence, and then tally words of the same length. Is this trying to make complexity out of simplicity?

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen( "foobar.txt", "r" );
    /* omitting check for failure */

    char buf[ 128 ];
    int wc = 0, lengths[ 50 ] = { 0 };
    while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, fp ) != NULL ) {
        /* add test for length >= 50 if paranoid about source data */
        lengths[ strlen( buf ) - 1 ]++;
        wc++; // word counter
    }

    fclose( fp );

    printf( "word count: %d\n", wc );
    for( int i = 1; i < sizeof lengths/sizeof lengths[0]; i++ )
        if( lengths[ i ] )
            printf( "words of %d letters: %d\n", i, lengths[ i ] );

    return 0;
}
```

A very few lines of code tallies the words of similar lengths. If some other functionality is required (eg: report words of 4-6 characters in sorted order), a trivial addition to these lines would achieve that result.

UNIX - the successful OS we know and love - was built on the principle of simplicity. In its early days, utilities like `cat`, `tr` and `sort` did one thing and did it well. These days, `cat` tries to be `cat` + `more` + `less` + `tail` + `number` + `paginate` + ... The "man page" for cat was 1 sentence: "Copy/concatenate files named as arguments ('-' == stdin) to stdout." Now the man page for `cat` goes on for several pages.

KISS, and move forward. Adding in the kitchen sink is not a good programming practice.

Comment: Yep, using a frequency-array is the only way to go here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's one of those days when a "rant" seems to ease the pressure... `:-)`